# Custom Tkinter button displaying the wrong character

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

So, I'm making a simple calculator in Python. I originally wrote this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

window_width = 200
window_height = 300

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width / 2)
center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height / 2)

root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')

def clear_text():
    entry_box.delete(0, END)

def print_one():
    entry_box.insert(END, "1")

def print_two():
    entry_box.insert(END, "2")

def print_three():
    entry_box.insert(END, "3")

def print_four():
    entry_box.insert(END, "4")

def print_five():
    entry_box.insert(END, "5")

def print_six():
    entry_box.insert(END, "6")

def print_seven():
    entry_box.insert(END, "7")

def print_eight():
    entry_box.insert(END, "8")

def print_nine():
    entry_box.insert(END, "9")

def print_zero():
    entry_box.insert(END, "0")

def print_plus():
    entry_box.insert(END, "+")

def print_minus():
    entry_box.insert(END, "-")

def print_divide():
    entry_box.insert(END, "/")

def print_multiply():
    entry_box.insert(END, "*")

def print_bracket0():
    entry_box.insert(END, "(")

def print_bracket1():
    entry_box.insert(END, ")")

def print_exponent():
    entry_box.insert(END, "**")

def do_maths():
    equation = entry_box.get()
    evaluate_equation = eval(equation)
    entry_box.delete(0, END)
    entry_box.insert(0, evaluate_equation)

simple_calculator = Label(root,text="Simple Calculator").place(x=30, y=10)

entry_text = StringVar()
entry_box = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_text)

one = Button(root, text="1", command=print_one).place(x=30,y=50)
two = Button(root, text="2", command=print_two).place(x=60, y=50)
three = Button(root, text="3", command=print_three).place(x=90, y=50)
four = Button(root, text="4", command=print_four).place(x=30, y=80)
five = Button(root, text="5", command=print_five).place(x=60, y=80)
six = Button(root, text="6", command=print_six).place(x=90, y=80)
seven = Button(root, text="7", command=print_seven).place(x=30, y=110)
eight = Button(root, text="8", command=print_eight).place(x=60, y=110)
nine = Button(root, text="9", command=print_nine).place(x=90, y=110)
zero = Button(root, text="0", command=print_zero).place(x=30, y=140)
plus = Button(root, text="+", command=print_plus).place(x=60, y=140)
minus = Button(root, text="-", command=print_minus).place(x=90, y=140)
divide = Button(root, text="/", command=print_divide).place(x=30, y=170)
multiply = Button(root, text="*", command=print_multiply).place(x=60, y=170)
equals = Button(root, text="=", command=do_maths).place(x=90, y=170)
bracket0 = Button(root, text="(", command=print_bracket0).place(x=30, y=200)
bracket1 = Button(root, text=")", command=print_bracket1).place(x=60, y=200)
exponent = Button(root, text="**", command=print_exponent).place(x=90, y=200)
clear = Button(root, text="Clear", command=clear_text).place(x=30, y=230)

entry_box.place(x=30, y=260)

root.mainloop()
```

which produces the first image.
However, I tried to rewrite the code using a different library, Custom Tkinter. This code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import customtkinter

root = customtkinter.CTk()

window_width = 200
window_height = 300

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width / 2)
center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height / 2)

root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')

def clear_text():
    entry_box.delete(0, END)

def print_one():
    entry_box.insert(END, "1")

def print_two():
    entry_box.insert(END, "2")

def print_three():
    entry_box.insert(END, "3")

def print_four():
    entry_box.insert(END, "4")

def print_five():
    entry_box.insert(END, "5")

def print_six():
    entry_box.insert(END, "6")

def print_seven():
    entry_box.insert(END, "7")

def print_eight():
    entry_box.insert(END, "8")

def print_nine():
    entry_box.insert(END, "9")

def print_zero():
    entry_box.insert(END, "0")

def print_plus():
    entry_box.insert(END, "+")

def print_minus():
    entry_box.insert(END, "-")

def print_divide():
    entry_box.insert(END, "/")

def print_multiply():
    entry_box.insert(END, "*")

def print_bracket():
    entry_box.insert(END, "(")

def print_bracket1():
    entry_box.insert(END, ")")

def print_exponent():
    entry_box.insert(END, "**")

def equate():
    equation = entry_box.get()
    evaluate_equation = eval(equation)
    entry_box.delete(0, END)
    entry_box.insert(0, evaluate_equation)

entry_text = StringVar()
entry_box = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_text)

#one = Button(root, text="1", command=print_one).place(x=30,y=50)
one = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="1", command=print_one).place(x=10,y=10)
#two = Button(root, text="2", command=print_two).place(x=60, y=50)
two = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="2", command=print_two).place(x=160,y=10)
#three = Button(root, text="3", command=print_three).place(x=90, y=50)
three = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="3", command=print_three).place(x=310,y=10)
#four = Button(root, text="4", command=print_four).place(x=30, y=80)
four = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="4", command=print_four).place(x=10,y=50)
#five = Button(root, text="5", command=print_five).place(x=60, y=80)
five = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="5", command=print_five).place(x=160,y=50)
#six = Button(root, text="6", command=print_six).place(x=90, y=80)
six = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="6", command=print_six).place(x=310,y=50)
#seven = Button(root, text="7", command=print_seven).place(x=30, y=110)
seven = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="7", command=print_seven).place(x=10,y=90)
#eight = Button(root, text="8", command=print_eight).place(x=60, y=110)
eight = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="8", command=print_eight).place(x=160,y=90)
#nine = Button(root, text="9", command=print_nine).place(x=90, y=110)
nine = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="9", command=print_nine).place(x=310,y=90)
#zero = Button(root, text="0", command=print_zero).place(x=30, y=140)
zero = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="0", command=print_zero).place(x=10,y=130)
#plus = Button(root, text="+", command=print_plus).place(x=60, y=140)
plus = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="+", command=print_plus).place(x=160, y=130)
#minus = Button(root, text="-", command=print_minus).place(x=90, y=140)
minus = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="-", command=print_minus).place(x=310, y=130)
#divide = Button(root, text="/", command=print_divide).place(x=30, y=170)
divide = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="/", command=print_divide).place(x=10, y=170)
#multiply = Button(root, text="*", command=print_multiply).place(x=60, y=170)
multiply = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="x", command=print_multiply).place(x=160, y=170)
#equals = Button(root, text="=", command=do_maths).place(x=90, y=170)
equals = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="=", command=equate).place(x=310, y=170)
#bracket = Button(root, text="(", command=print_bracket).place(x=30, y=200)
bracket = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="(", command=print_bracket).place(x=10, y=210)
#bracket1 = Button(root, text=")", command=print_bracket1).place(x=60, y=200)
bracket1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="(", command=print_bracket1).place(x=160, y=210)
#exponent = Button(root, text="**", command=print_exponent).place(x=90, y=200)
exponent = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="^^", command=print_exponent).place(x=310, y=210)
#clear = Button(root, text="Clear", command=clear_text).place(x=30, y=230)
clear = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="Clear", command=clear_text).place(x=160, y=250)


entry_box = Entry(font=('Arial 24'))
entry_box.place(x=170, y=450)

root.mainloop()
```

That produces the second image.
Basically, I have no idea where I went wrong. Pardon my ignorance, but my code looks okay to me - the only changes to the original are that I've commented out the original buttons and re-written them using the syntax of Custom Tkinter. However, as you can see in the second image, the buttons for the brackets display only the left bracket "(". Can anyone help?

[Image of a simple Tkinter calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deiMY.png)

[Image of a simple Custom Tkinter calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKRS7.png)

Comment: Because you wrote it so: `bracket1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="(", command=print_bracket1).place(x=160, y=210)`

Comment: It would help if you reduced the amount of code to only that which is necessary to illustrate the problem. If there is no problem with buttons 0-9, there's no need to included them in the example. See [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

In your second block of code, you wrote:

```
bracket1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="(", command=print_bracket1).place(x=160, y=210)
```

This was meant to display the ")" symbol. However, you set

```
text="("
```

This would set the symbol to "(" instead of ")".
If you look at your original block of code, you set it to the correct symbol. This is why there is a difference.

I would recommend setting `window_width` and `window_height` to all uppercase. It should look like this `WINDOW_WIDTH` and this `WINDOW_HEIGHT`. The reason for this is to show that these variables are constants, meaning they never change and are always *constant*. This is recommended in the [Python style guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). There are other parts where you can increase readability, but I wouldn't worry about readability or the style guides in your first few projects. All you need to do is get used to the syntax and solve problems. Let me know if you need more of an explanation!